# How to modify appointment with soap api in zimbra?

Tags: xml, soap, zimbra

Im trying to modify a simple zimbra event though it's SOAP API, but zimbra documentation does not tell well which basic data are required. So I'm so lost :[

Actually im sending this request body, and I get a `service.PARSE_ERROR` that doesn't help much ...

```
<ModifyAppointmentRequest id="1192-1191" ms="2616" rev="2616" comp="0">
    <m su="Test subject" l="10">
        <e a="mail@mail.com" t="f" p="Test user"/>
        <inv uid="_the_uid_" type="appt">
            <comp name="Test subject" loc="My location" allDay="0" status="CONF" fb="B" class="PUB" transp="O" draft="1">
                <at role="REQ" ptst="AC" rsvp="0" a="mail@mail.com" d="mail@mail.com"/>
                <s d="20160413T160000" tz="Europe/Paris"/>
                <e d="20160413T170000" tz="Europe/Paris"/>
                <or a="mail@mail.com" d="Test user"/>
            </comp>
        </inv>
    </m>
</ModifyAppointmentRequest>
```

This request is based on zimbra web ajax request sent json when I modify an event.

What do I forget ? Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
<e a="mail@mail.com" t="f" p="Test user"/>
```

into

```
<e a="mail@mail.com" t="t" p="Test user"/>
```

I've tried and it's working.

Comment: owww, soz, I finally found the error, was in the sending method. Was using an old shitty PHP base function that was adding properties in the closing tag of the request. Sending it with cURL & building it with SimpleXMLElement is much more efficient :) Thanks for the try :)